# aptana studio 3 - spelling is not installed

Tags: aptana

Looking through the preferences I can see the option to turn on the spell checker but I get a "spelling is not installed" message.

I've searched for help on this, but all I can find is old posts about the feature not being ready - seems strange to not have this feature yet. Does anyone have any idea about this?

I hope that its OK posting on stackoverflow about this - their support page links here and I see other people have asked too.

Answer (score 3):

I use Aptana 3.2.2 and followed this blog post:
http://jebaird.com/blog/useful-plugins-aptana-studio-3

It works for me.

Excerpt from the blog post:

> **Hunspell**
>
> Url:
>   http://hunspell4eclipse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/com.lorands.hunspell4eclipse.updatesite/
>
> This will add a spelling service to Aptana. You will also need to
>   download the dictionary files for this plugin. I decided to use
>   chromium’s dictionary files over the default. You can read and
>   download them from here:
>
> http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries
>
> At minimum you will need an *.aff and *.dic fiile. To make it easy on
>   you, I have included the en_US version of these files in this post.
>
> After you install the plugin you will need to go to Window >
>   Preferences > then General > Editors > Text Editors > Spelling. And
>   tell the plugin where the dictionary files are.